# Cocoa/iOS: How to add a file as attachment to a PDF document?

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, cocoa, pdf

PDF files support embedding arbitrary files as attachments ([see here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Document_Format#File_attachments)).

I would like to do just that in a Mac and an iPhone application using Objective-C:

1. Add a file as attachment to a PDF
2. Read the list of attached files from a PDF and extract one

Use case:

My app uses a custom document format that can only be opened by the app. I'd like to export the document as PDF and embed the original, custom document so that users who happen to have the app installed can modify the document. Everybody else can still open and print the PDF.

Comment: You would have to evaluate a third party component as neither [Quartz nor Cocoa](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/PDFKitGuide/PDFKit_Prog_Conc/PDFKit_Prog_Conc.html) provide this specific function

Comment: @mahaltertin Are you aware of any Open Source projects that would work on Mac OS X and iOS?

Comment: [PSPDFKit](http://pspdfkit.com) supports embedded attachments. See: http://pspdfkit.com/api/Classes/PSPDFEmbeddedFile.html

Answer (score 1):

You can do this easily with the iOS version of the [Debenu Quick PDF Library](http://www.debenu.com/products/development/debenu-pdf-library). Download the sample project and modify it with the sample code below:

**How to embed a file**

```
[DQPL LoadFromFile:path_of_my_PDF_file :@""];  //load your existing PDF file
[DQPL EmbedFile:@"Original_custom_document" :path_of_the_original_custom_document :@""]; //specify the name and the location of the attachment
[DQPL SaveToFile:new_path];
```

**How to find the filenames of the attachments (skip if you have only one attached file)**

```
[DQPL LoadFromFile:new_path :@""];
NSString *listItem;
int fileCount = [DQPL EmbeddedFileCount]; //returns the number of attached files
for( int count = 1; count <= fileCount; count++ ){
listItem = [DQPL GetEmbeddedFileStrProperty:count :1]; //returns the filename of the attached file
//show/read or save the returned filenames and the index of it...
}
```

**How to extract an attached file**

```
[DQPL LoadFromFile:new_path :@""];
[DQPL GetEmbeddedFileContentToFile:1 :path_and_filename_to_write_the_extracted_attachment]; //specify where do you want to save the extracted attachment (in this case the index of the attachment is 1)
```

Pal
(Debenu Team)

Comment: Thanks,This is very useful for me.
I just want to know any another way for the same because this library is paid.